# Can I return case values of switch statement? Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

Trying to make a swift file with all kinds of permissions for iPhone including

- Camera,
- Photos library,
- Contacts,
- Location Services,
- Microphone.

So I tried searching, ***How to know if user has access to Camera***?

and mostly getting functions with `Switch statements`. What I am looking for is universal functions to call anywhere in project e:g after calling function elsewhere in project I want to able to perform if case `.authorised` then do code A `elseif` .denied then do code B else `.notDetermined` do code C.

```
func checkPhotoLibraryPermission() {
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        print("Authorized")
    case .denied, .restricted :
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("Authorized")
            case .denied, .restricted:
                print("No access")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Not determined")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with the help of blocks.

```
public typealias CompletionHandler = ((Bool)->Void)?

  @objc func yourMethod(completionBlock : CompletionHandler){
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        completionBlock(true);
    case .denied, .restricted :
         completionBlock(false);
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                 completionBlock(true);
            case .denied, .restricted:
                 completionBlock(false);
            case .notDetermined:
                 completionBlock(false);
           }
        }
        }
    }
```

This is just a sample you can write accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need a callback function as `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization()` is an async operation.

```
func checkPhotoLibraryPermission(callback:(authorized:Bool)->Void) {
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        callback(true)
    case .denied, .restricted :
         callback(false)
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                 callback(true)
            case .denied, .restricted,.notDetermined:
                 callback(false)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func checkPhotoLibraryPermission() -> Bool {
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        print("Authorized")

        return true
    case .denied:

        return true

    case .restricted :

          return false

    case .notDetermined:

         return false

        }
    }

}
```

something like this ?? if yes then it's great and if no then let me know what exactly you want so i can try to code switch case as per your requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your function with return type

```
func isPhotoLibraryPermission() -> bool {
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
        case .authorized:
           print("Authorized")
           return true
        case .denied, .restricted :
           return false
        case .notDetermined:
           PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
              switch status {
                  case .authorized:
                      print("Authorized")
                      return true
                  case .denied, .restricted:
                      print("No access")
                      return false
                  case .notDetermined:
                      print("Not determined")
                      return false
             }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If you need something more generic, create enum with all cases you want to return and then return that :-)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply I'll try that (: